# Eyedropper picks wrong color V3.6

Tags: color, color-management

I try to use the eyedropper to pick a paint color I've used before and it always gets the color wrong. I looked up the problem which suggests changing the color management settings (which I did) and under objects - visibility - grease pencil to change the use lights setting to false (which doesn't show up for me). I thought maybe it was just a setting I might have messed up in the project so I opened a new one and it had the same problem immediately.